# moving a command to a different host template using icinga director

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

I have Icinga2 installed with icingaweb2 on Ubuntu 19.10 and I have Icinga director Installed for the configuration which is really awesome.

I created some command and attached them to linux-agent host template.

that was a mistake cause I added more servers that don't need these new commands.

so I created a new host template called my-linux-agent as a duplicate of linux-agent and now I want to move all my custom commands to the new host template and I can't find any way to do that.

versions:
Icinga2: 2.10.5
IcingaWeb2: 2.7.1

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i couldn't find a way to move the command to a different host directly

but you can easily duplicate the command to a different host and remove the previous one using the following simple steps:

1. open the relevant command
2. click on `duplicate` to duplicate the command
3. choose the relevant host and click save
4. open the previous command and delete it